# Wsimport not including wsdl in client jar when wsdl is from url

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

We are managing our wsdl from a Repository, and in order to prevent copying the wsdl locally and getting out of sync, We've set up our client (and service) poms to pull from the URL at build time.

The problem is the client jar doesn't included the wsdls in its META-INF folder.  Whenever we try to use the client to call our service, we get this error:

```
08/22/2013@10:24 FATAL     -  2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of
InaccessibleWSDLException.

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: "Repo-url"
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: "Repo-url"
```

Here is the part of the pom using wsimport:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
            </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <xauthFile>${basedir}/resources/authFile.txt</xauthFile>
            <wsdlUrls>               
                    <wsdlUrl>"Repo-url"</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
            <bindingFiles>
            <bindingFile>${basedir}/resources/binding.xjb.xml</bindingFile>
            </bindingFiles>
                <keep>true</keep>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

How can I tell the plugin to also include the wsdl into the jar folder when building this way?

Answer (score 0):

Can your try with this annotation in your client.

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "WSClient", targetNamespace = "http://yournamespace.com", wsdlLocation ="META-INF/wsdl/WSClient.wsdl"
```

Comment: We already have that annotation in, however the wsdlLocation is pointed at that "repo-url" rather than meta-inf/wsdl/.  Seems like part of the overall problem of it not including the wsdl in the meta-inf folder of the jar.